# Create Address Labels with data retrieved from Database table

Tags: labels

I'm trying to load an Excel file, make several selections and print that selection in labels, the traditional post labels with the destination address.

The part of managing the database, the table and the selections is ok, but I've been researching (I'm real newbie at Wordpress, I'm still searching a lot) and I'm not able to find a solution to print the address labels. Every search goes to "email" when I'm searching for simple "mail", and there are only Woocommerce solutions, and I do not want/need to use that.

Could someone give me a hand, I'm becoming desperate, and starting to look for the Word Mail Merge as the discovery of the Wheel.

Comment: can you expand on this more? It's clear you want to print address labels, and somehow involve WordPress, but it's unclear where and how you're storing this information. It's also unclear if you're trying to export the data to a format Excel can read, or trying to make WordPress talk directly to your printer

Comment: I load the Excel table to "WP Data Acess" and the data stays in the DB where the different selections are made. I would prefere to have the all process made in Wordpress (this is a project for a NGO and they have litle/none informatic knowledge ), but please if you have different solutions, they are welcomed

Comment: oooh you're using the https://wpdataaccess.com/ plugin and want to print address labels based on the data you stored. You need to ask their support or post in one of their communities, questions about 3rd party plugins are offtopic here. Unless they provide an addon it's unlikely you'll find something that doesn't require you to write code